# How do I Push/add entries from Lambda response to environment variables in Python dynamically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do I Push/add entries from Lambda response to environment variables in Python dynamically?

Basically I'm getting a response which contains key values, could be 1 or more. Depending on the length of array of objects I want to push them into environment variables and use it for upcoming calls.

Comment: Please show us some code and tell us specifically what you're trying to achieve and what you're struggling with.

Comment: Im Fetching sns subscription arns by sending a req with email and topic arns. i want to store subscriptionArns so whenever unsubscription call happens i can get this subscriptionArn value and send the same to unsubscribe.(SNS Topics), Im using Python in lambda

Answer (score 1):

Changing the system's environment variable during the function execution won't help here because Lambda does not maintain the state among different executions.

What you can do instead is update the Lambda config using [update-function-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html). You can look for **update-function-configuration** in the API SDK for the language that you are using.